# emacs orgmode table use the equal sign without starting a formula

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm typing up a table with org mode, where the equal sign(=) if the first character in the cell and it want to start a formula. how do I get it to display the symbol without it being a formula, of a way to use formulas to display it. I get errors when I use single quotes, and I see the Unicode decimal value when using double quotes.
I have tried the following

```
='=+'
="=+"
```

they give

```
#ERROR
[61, 43]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an escaped entity, `\equal{}` and it should display as you wish.  See the variable `org-entities` for others you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late :D

There may be a better way, but you can try with `:='(format "=+")`

Source: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19183/can-i-use-formula-to-manipulate-text-in-org-mode-table

Answer (score -1):

When I ran into this problem just now, I found that I was able to get around it by replacing the equals sign with some other similar-looking character. Two which come to mind are `꞊` ‘U+A78A MODIFIER LETTER SHORT EQUALS SIGN’ and `⹀` ‘U+2E40 DOUBLE HYPHEN’.